# How to include a condition inside a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I know for singular results, I can do something like this:

```
return "this is a condition test within a string - " +  {0:'&#x26AA;',1:'&#x1f7e1;',2:'&#x1f534;',3:'&#x1f7e2',8:'',9:''}[event.FlagInd.toString()]
```

where `0`, `1`, `2` etc are values from the variable `event.FlagInd`, and the results are the values inside the quoted strings such as `'&#x26AA;'` etc

So in the example above, a value of 1 in the `event.FlagID`, replaces the 1 with  - a yellow ball

I am trying to do something similar, to "turn on or off" actual HTML inside a string.

My current attempts return invalid strings or the strings are not formed correctly.

```
 return
        "<strong style=\"font-size:18px;\">" +
        {
            0: '', default: "<a href=\" + "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:" + event.imo +
                "/vessel:" + event.text + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + event.text + "</a>"' }[event.imo.toString()] +
            "</strong>" + ... etc
```

What I am trying to do is return an empty string if the value of `event.IMO = 0`, but to return this entire  html string, if the value is something other than 0 ...

```
"<a href=\"https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:" + event.imo + "/vessel:" + event.text + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + event.text + "</a>"
```

Comment: Use a conditional statement? `n == 0 ? 'true' : 'false'`

Comment: Thanks but 'n' is a string, not a number as per the .toString() in my example

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only reason you use `.toString()` is so you can use it to index an object. If you're just comparing against `0`, you don't need to convert to a string.

Comment: You're the winner! It worked with a little bit extra. My answer below. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ouroborus, I was able to do it... as per this example:

```
function myResult(IMO, text){
     return "Answer is " + 
        (IMO.toString() == 0 ? "nothing here" :
      "<strong style=\"font-size:18px;\">" +
      "<a href=\"https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:" + IMO +
      "/vessel:" + text + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + text + "</a>" + 
      "</strong>")
}
 
document.write(myResult("0123","myShip"))
```

Changing the value from "0123" to "0" gives me the "nothing here", otherwise it's the HTML entirely. Just got to make sure you format the HTML as a string correctly.